# Problems with positioning and divs over jQuery image carousels

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

My knowledge of Javascript is rudimentary at best (I'm not a coder by trade), but I'm trying to cobble a page together such that there are two divs sitting on top of a jQuery image carousel. [This page](http://jtroll.com/chd/web/index.html) is the example of what I'm talking about, with this screen grab showing how it should look in proper fighting form: jtroll.com/chd/web/properform.png (as a first-time poster, stackoverflow won't let me attach more than one proper link. Sorry).

My first problem was trying to figure out how to do some sort of positioning trickery so that I could throw both the div `#cta_imgbox_learnmore` and `#img_boxout` on top of the jQuery carousel, `#slideblock`. I made a silly additional wrapper div, called `box1_home`, thinking this would help in that effort (because when I tried to put those divs inside of `#slideblock`, it screwed up the image cycle in the carousel).

I did some `position:relative` tomfoolery, only to realize it was pushing the entire `#slideblock` down the page according to the height of `#cta_imgbox_learnmore`. Bad news. So of course, I thought giving `#slideblock` a negative top margin might be a decent way to hack around this.

Once I added the second div `#img_boxout` though, it all went to hell. The text I'm trying to flow into that div is being pushed to the side, and I had to add even more ridiculous negative margin to the top of `#slideblock`. Not cool.

So I guess my question is: what's a better, cleaner, smarter way to do this, that won't screw up the jQuery carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to get the position of the element you want to use as reference.

Supposing `#carrousel` as the slider element and `#block` as the element you want above it (using jQuery) :

```
var ob = $('#carrousel').offset();
$('#block').css({ 'top': ob.top, 'left': ob.left }).show();
```

This is just an example. You may have to work those values out to get exacly what you want. Note that you should create `#block` but hiding it with css, so that it would not show untill it's "his time to shine".

**EDIT** : The working example :

css

```
#carrousel_text
{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2000; // might need to be changed if you can't see it
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px; // change to whatever you need
  height: 100px; // change to whatever you need
  background: red; // so that you can see what you're doing
}
```

js

```
// the one you already have, do not creae another instance of jquery
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

// gets the top and left position of the #slideblock
var ob = $('#slideblock').offset();
// adds the top and left position to the #carrousel_text and shows it where you want it
// note that you'll have to sum or substract to ob.top and ob.left accordingly to what you visually need, e.g. untill it's in the right place.
$('#carrousel_text').css({ 'top': ob.top+50, 'left': ob.left+50 }).show();
```

Lastly, you can just insert your #carrousel_text on the markup, anywhere you want (it's irrelevant) and place the other divs inside it, like :

```
<div id="carrousel_text">
  <div id="cta_imgbox_learnmore">
    <a id="cta_img_learnmore" href="#" title="Learn More"><span>Learn More</span></a>
  </div>    
  <div id="img_boxout">
    <p>Read our story and our methodology in crafting your custom home</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure where one would implement the type of code you referenced here. Is this... Javascript? In the header? Or in one of the separate .js files?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, anywhere as long as it follows the common practice of the library. As long as you have the CSS for the carrousel (the container) it should work just fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't know enough code to understand the wisdom you're trying to impart. Ah, well. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What might be applicable beyond the source code for the page above (http://jtroll.com/chd/web/index.html)?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion: that's my code. The explanation above is the specific problem I'm having with that page.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm fairly certain I was able to follow your suggestions to the letter, and everything worked until I added the #carrousel_text div around the carousel. After that, the whole carousel disappeared. I've updated the link with the code I changed: http://jtroll.com/chd/web/index.html

Comment: #slideblock isn't supposed to be inside #carrousel_text. I've pasted the example markup on the post exacly to prevent you from doing that .. :)

Comment: Ack, right then! That solves that! But now that that's done, #carrousel_text isn't visible. I've tried adjusting the z-index, to no avail...

Comment: Have you pasted the CSS on your code? Can't find it .. Also, can't find the javascript I've written on your code. One more thing, now the elements inside #carrousel_text should be CSS'ed accordingly to their new parent (no more messy margins as it was your initial problem)

Comment: Sorry, cache problem. Everything seems fine except you missed one line of the javascript : var ob = $('#slideblock').offset();

Put it before the other one I gave you.

Comment: That seemed to do weird things to the carousel; whenever I positioned the .offset line above the lines for slideblock, it did this (this is using the pastebin lines): http://jtroll.com/chd/web/index_jq.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change some things, should work now : http://pastebin.com/V93aLNbR

Comment: You win! That definitely worked. Now I just have this bizarre problem where img_boxout refuses to justify correctly to the left. Which... well, it's not jQuery, but any ideas? Because that sort of feeds into what I *thought* was part of my original problem. If not, no worries, you've been a big help.

Comment: now you have to adapt the CSS of everything inside #carrousel_text, since now what's inside is related to #carrousel_text, not to what it was before. Should also be simpler now, there's not much to it .. no need to crazy margins or anything like that.

Comment: Er, one final question: it seems that now that the #carrousel_text is sitting on top of the jQuery carousel, you can no longer click upon the carousel to advance the images. Is it an impossibility to bring that back, since we've now created a div that sits on top of #slideblock?

Comment: It's a common problem, with 2 options : 1st, make #carrousel_text as small as you can, accordingly to it's contents (leaving more space available to be clicked on #slideblock). 2nd, use this : http://pastebin.com/bB64AkhW

Comment: ...And uh, this is embarrassing, but any idea why the carousel has disappeared completely once I ported it all over into WordPress? http://www.cypresshilldevelopment.com/

Comment: no idea, not used to work with wordpress, but it might have rewritted something on the code.